# Upload blob with Set-AzStorageBlobContent via pipeline and set ContentType property

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

Using the `Az` PowerShell module, I'm trying to enumerate a directory on disk and pipe the output to `Set-AzStorageBlobContent` to upload to Azure, while preserving the folder structure. This works great, except the `ContentType` property of all blobs is set to `application/octet-stream`. I'd like to set it dynamically based on the file extension of the blob being uploaded.

Here's example code for the base case:

```
Get-ChildItem $SourceRoot -Recurse -File |
    Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $ContainerName -Context $context -Force
```

To set the `ContentType`, I need to add a `Properties` parameter to `Set-AzStorageBlobContent` with a value like `@{ "ContentType" = "<content type>" }`. The content type should be determined from the specific file extension being uploaded. I've written a separate pipelined function that can add a `MimeType` property to the file object, but I can't figure out how to reference that for the parameter in the pipeline. Example:

```
function Add-MimeType{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(
            Mandatory           = $true,
            ValueFromPipeline   = $true)]
        $pipelineInput
    )
    Process {
        $mimeType = Get-MimeType $pipelineInput.Extension
        Add-Member -InputObject $pipelineInput -NotePropertyName "MimeType" -NotePropertyValue $mimeType
        return $pipelineInput
    }
}

function Get-MimeType(
    [string]$FileExtension
)
{
    switch ($FileExtension.ToLowerInvariant())
    {
        '.txt'  { return 'text/plain' }
        '.xml'  { return 'text/xml' }
        default { return 'application/octet-stream' }
    }
}

Get-ChildItem $SourceRoot -Recurse -File |
    Add-MimeType |
        Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $ContainerName -Properties @{"ContentType" = "$($_.MimeType)"} -Context $context -Force
```

It seems that `$_` isn't usable in this context. Is there another way to accomplish this?

The reason I'd like to continue using pipelining is that it appears to work much faster than using a `ForEach-Object` loop to call the function (where `$_` does work).

Comment: Could you provide your function `Add-MimeType` here?

Comment: @JoyWang Added!

Comment: @Dan did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @MyItchyChin No, I never did. I just ended up using a `ForEach-Object` loop to call it for each file so it can have the proper mime type.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to completely different solutions, you can also use [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10).

You can upload your whole [folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#upload-files) with one command, and AzCopy can also automatically guess the correct mime type based on the file extension. There is also support for [Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops), if that is part of your setup.

Command could look something like this:

```
# AzCopy v10 will automatically guess the content type unless you pass --no-guess-mime-type
azcopy copy 'C:\myDirectory' 'https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer' --recursive

# AzCopy V8
azcopy copy 'C:\myDirectory' 'https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer' /s /SetContentType
```

Taken from the output of `AzCopy.exe copy --help`:

> AzCopy automatically detects the content type of the files when uploading from the local disk, based on the file extension or content (if no extension is specified).
>
> The built-in lookup table is small, but on Unix, it is augmented by the local system's mime.types file(s) if available under one or more of these names:
>
> - /etc/mime.types
> - /etc/apache2/mime.types
> - /etc/apache/mime.types
>
> On Windows, MIME types are extracted from the registry. This feature can be turned off with the help of a flag. Please refer to the flag section.

Comment: Thanks; I should have mentioned that this wasn't an option. I'm running this code in an Azure Function where (based on past experience) running AzCopy wasn't an ideal setup. I appreciate the details, though!